# jQuery Slider - Images seem jerky :/

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I've been working on this:
http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/workingon/swots/

As you can see, the images seem to jerk when I would like one to fade into another smoothly. Any Ideas?

Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using huge images so this is overkill for browsers. You should also consider integrating CSS3 animations as those are usually rendered a lot smoother than javascript-based animations.

Comment: You can't rely on CSS3 as much as you can jQuery.   There's still lots of browsers that don't support it.

Comment: Ahhhhh I seem to have fixed it. The images were loading underneath eachother not on top of eachother. Setting the position top: 0 and left: 0 seems to have worked.

Comment: @Archer i know a lot of browsers don't support CSS3 but then a lot do at the moment so using libs like Modernizr to decide which animation technique to use (and creating a lot of if-else statements) pays off for consumer sites

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using images with 4mb of size, too heavy to initial load.

If you want them not distorted you have to take off the `height:100%` of the image, so it will be cropped.

Comment: Its not the distortion of the images that I am asking about. I am just trying to get the problem with the fadein/out fixed. It seems to fade out then snap in the next image. Not a smooth transition.. :/

Comment: Your .simple-slider element should have "position:absolute" to stay one above another an them fades to them. With position relative, your another image is down the other, thats because you cant get the effect of fade.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhhh I seem to have fixed it. The images were loading underneath eachother not on top of eachother. Setting the position top: 0 and left: 0 seems to have worked.

Thanks guys